# Is it possible to use another transition for showing a dialog than for hiding

Tags: dart, flutter-animation, animatewithduration, flutter-dialog

When using showGeneralDialog - is it possible to use a different transition and duration for displaying a dialog than for hiding the dialog again?

E.g. a Curves.elasticOut for showing and a shorter Curve.linear transition for hiding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [showGeneralDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/showGeneralDialog.html) method has the following signature:

```
Future<T?> showGeneralDialog<T extends Object?>(
{required BuildContext context,
required RoutePageBuilder pageBuilder,
bool barrierDismissible = false,
String? barrierLabel,
Color barrierColor = const Color(0x80000000),
Duration transitionDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
RouteTransitionsBuilder? transitionBuilder,
bool useRootNavigator = true,
RouteSettings? routeSettings,
Offset? anchorPoint}
)
```

Per the documentation, the RouteTransitionBuilder object :

> "...is used to define how the route arrives on and leaves off the screen.
> By default, the transition is a linear fade of the page's contents."

The [RouteTransitionBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteTransitionsBuilder.html) has the following signature:

```
RouteTransitionsBuilder = Widget Function(
BuildContext context,
Animation<double> animation,
Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
Widget child
)
```

The two Animation objects are used for:

> animation: When the Navigator pushes a route on the top of its stack,
> the new route's primary animation runs from 0.0 to 1.0. When the
> Navigator pops the topmost route this animation runs from 1.0 to 0.0.
> secondaryAnimation: When the Navigator pushes a new route on the top
> of its stack, the old topmost route's secondaryAnimation runs from 0.0
> to 1.0. When the Navigator pops the topmost route, the
> secondaryAnimation for the route below it runs from 1.0 to 0.0.

If you want to have a different animation and duration, you can create your own RouteTransitionBuilder with its own animations and attach an [animationController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) to it with a specific duration.